# Check if value in a string is closer to system time

Tags: c#, file, time

I need to check if the value in the string i have that comes from a file, is closer to the system time. I don't want to check if it equals to. The value should be +5 or -5 mins with in the range of the system time.

```
e.g. If value from file is : 060700, and system time is 060500 OR 060900 
     I want to return a true
```

I can parse the filetime as:

```
DateTime filTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

and then get the current system time as:

```
DateTime curTime = DateTime.Now;
```

But now how should I check for +5 or -5 min range. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could establish 2 variables with

```
DateTime dtPlus5 = curTime.AddMinutes(5);
DateTime dtMinus5 = curTime.AddMinutes(-5);
```

and then check them against curTime

```
if (filTime >= dtMinus5 && filTime <= dtPlus5) 
{
   // Bingo!!!
}
```

Untested but should work

Answer (score 5):

```
TimeSpan diff = curTime - fileTime;
bool inRange = diff.Duration().TotalMinutes <= 5;
```

[`TimeSpan.Duration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.duration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns the absolute timespan.

Comment: You can also create `TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)` and then just compare this timespan with duration

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Subtract method [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

something like:

```
double minuteDiff = Math.Abs(t1.Subtract(t2).TotalMinutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the date from the file too not just the time and then use the following to get the difference in seconds.

```
var differenceInSeconds = (dateTime1 - dateTime2).TotalSeconds;
```

Comment: I'm just interested in the time for my purpose

Comment: It's upto you, but what if it executes just past midnight? It will be within 5 minutes range as we know it, but your program will say it's about 24hrs difference in time. Also 8mins is 1 minute difference from 7mins59secs if you only count minutes, or is it? is that fine too ?